# Why are there differences in data when comparing table to itself? TSQL

Tags: t-sql, table

I'm comparing two tables that should have the same data.  I've got a couple of different queries that are supposed to return rows that don't match.  However, the queries return rows that DO match.  I'm not sure why.  Here is an example:

```
select 
which = 'TableA',
*
from (
select * from compareTempA
except
select * from compareTempB
) x
union all
select
'TableB',
*
from (
select * from compareTempB
except
select * from compareTempA

) x
order by dateindex, empid, serviceSales, productSales
```

For some reason I get results like the following:

[image: Query Results]

As you can see these rows appear to match.  I've also tried:

```
select sum(case when A.productSales = B.productSales then 0 else 1 end) from 
compareTempA A
join compareTempB B
on A.dateindex = B.dateindex
and A.empid = B.empid
and A.storeid = B.storeid
```

To which I get 3011.  I'm baffled because the data is supposed to be the same in both tables.  The only thing I can think of is that I formed the two tables by inserting into each of them in the following way:

```
insert into compareTempA
select * from someView
```

And I did the same for compareTempB.  I tried truncating the tables first and reinserting.  Please help!

Comment: dateindex column type? Is it INT, CHAR, DATE... DATETIME?

Comment: dateindex column type is an INT.  Is this an issue?

Comment: What is the primary key of the tables? Can you provide the CREATE TABLE statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that you are not using the same data type for the column `productSales` on both tables.

For example, if your data type on `compareTempA` is `float` and on `compareTempB` is `decimal`, that's exactly what should happen.

By the way, this happens even if both columns are `float`, due to the fact that `float` is not a precise datatype.

I suggest that you change your datatype to a precise one, like `decimal`.

"Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. The ISO synonym for real is float(24)."
**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

### Similar problems:

**Same problem here -** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149966/comparing-2-float-values-in-sqlserver

**Best Pratices Red Gate -** https://documentation.red-gate.com/codeanalysis/best-practice-rules/bp023

**Another question about floats and precise comparisions -** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737004/should-we-use-float-as-primary-key-in-sql-server

Comment: same datatype.  float for both.

Comment: Is it possible to use a decimal type? for definition, float is a approximate data type and should not be used for index or precise comparisons

Comment: You could also, only on your except, add a cast to decimal(15,4) - for instance - on your float column, instead of using only *

Comment: Yep.  That's the issue.  I changed the type from float to decimal.  Now the first query i mentioned above is returning only one difference.  PorductSales of 57 on compareTempB and 58 on compareTempA.  I can live with this.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @J4ce - you're dealing with monetary values, which should never be stored/processed as (binary) floats, but some sort of base-10 decimal, because that's the "Actual" type of the number.  For some issues, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples).